# How can i download geotagged tweets related to Kerala flood?

Tags: python-3.x

How can i download geo-tagged tweets related to **Kerala flood** in python?
I am doing a project in twitter sentiment analysis, it will be helpful if you can help me with the dataset part.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.